# Checking one Pandas Dataframe for Elements to Update Another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with identical columns.  The second column is a subset of the index values of the first but has empty fields for some of the columns and updated information for others.

Example:

dfa:

```
         Height    Weight   Age   Street  PhoneNumber

Pete       5.2       130     33    Pine    123-456-7890
Mary       5.0       110     34    Main    434-444-5555
Rob        6.0       230     44    Maple   999-444-2222
....
```

dfb:

```
        Height    Weight   Age   Street  PhoneNumber

Pete      Nan        125     Nan    Arbor      Nan
Rob       Nan        235     45     Nan    776-333-3222
```

I want to update the fields in `dfa` with the new information in `dfb`. If there is no update from `dfb` (the field is Nan) I want to keep the original value in `dfa`.

The only way I can think to do this is to iterate by row and column, find the elements in `dfb` and then set the corresponding address in `dfa` equal to the address in `dfb`.  Ugly.

Is there a cleaner (and more pythonic) way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  Changed dfb for clarity.  The two dfs do not have identical indexes.  dfb is a subset of dfa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first) make sure those "Nan" are really np.nan first:

```
dfb = dfb.replace('Nan',np.nan)
dfb.combine_first(dfa)
```

Output:

```
      Height Weight Age Street   PhoneNumber
Pete     5.2    125  33  Arbor  123-456-7890
Mary     5.0    110  34   Main  434-444-5555
Rob      6.0    235  45  Maple  776-333-3222
```

Comment: Interesting. The documentation says 'a's values prioritized using b's to fill holes'. I haven't tested yet but it appears if I understand correctly that a's values are used (even if null) but are replaced if there is a non-null value from b where index.a = = index.b. is that right?

Comment: The output is from `dfb`.  You then either need to reassign it to `dfa` or then use `dfb` henceforth as the completed dataframe.  I believe `update` is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Only cleaner if you want to loose your change tracking in your original dataframe.  I think it safer if you give the user a choice to reassign or create a new dfc, therefore if needed be they can go back to the original dataframe.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 in this case because I did dfb.combine_fist(dfa) it gives "dfb values prioritized using dfa's to fill holes".

Comment: @ScottBoston - ....and since it takes the union of the dataframes I get all the rows in dfa that weren't in dfb in the result!

Answer (score 1):

If the index of dfb is the same as dfa, maybe using some mask, something like

```
mask = dfb.notnull()
dfa[mask] = dfb[mask]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the indexes are not the same.  dfb.index is a subset of dfa.index

Comment: apparently (i made a check) it works even if dfb index and columns are a subset of dfa, anyway I found the other solutions more proper

Comment: Thanks.  I'm completely unfamiliar with masks.  I'll have to read up to figure out how to apply.  Is the concept with a mask to just 'group identify' values in one object so they can be applied to a second identical (or nearly identical) object?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is common terminology, but given an array `A`, I call `mask` for it any array of booleans of the same shape of A. Then, calling `A[mask]` will select all elements of `A` that are in a `True` position. For instance, `mask = A < 5` and `A[mask] = 0` will set to 0 all elements in `A` smaller than 5. The same applies to pandas DataFrame, and since in pandas you have more indexing options you can do also more fancy stuff, as above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `fillna()`, take a look here
[link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

in your case just doing `dfb.fillna(dfa)` should work

Comment: That's cool.  I was unaware you can use fillna() on a dataframe level like that.  However please see my edit.  dfb is actually a subset of dfa observations.  So if I did `dfb.fillna(dfa)`  I'd lose all the rows in `dfa` that aren't in `dfb`.  is there a twist on your suggestion that might work?

Comment: It works the same, at least in the test I made, otherwise the combine_first() looks very appealing

Comment: `fillna` just updates the NaN values in `dfa` with the values from `dfb`.  The OP requested that all non-null values from `dfb` are used to update `dfa`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to [update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) your original dataframe:

```
dfa.update(dfb)

>>> dfa

        Height  Weight  Age Street  PhoneNumber
Pete    5.2     125     33  Arbor   123-456-7890
Mary    5.0     110     34  Main    434-444-5555
Rob     6.0     235     45  Maple   776-333-3222
```

`update` modifies the original dataFrame in place using non-NA values from the second dataFrame.